# Intense lagging while playing games (Space Engine)

Tags: hardware, graphics-card, space-engine

I have played SpaceEngine **(NOT Space-Engineers)** on my laptop for almost a year now without any problems. However the game has started experiencing a lot of lag for the last one month. I opened up task manager to try and figure out what was causing the lag. This is what I saw.

[image]

The GPU was being used at 100%. This is very strange because the game usually (when it was not lagging) uses only 70% of its GPU while simulating space (because that is less graphics intensive) and about 90% GPU while simulating planetary terrain (because that is more graphics intensive). However now its using the whole 100% for space itself which causes it to lag on planets because it cannot use more than 100% graphics.

I don't understand why it is doing this. Why is the game using the entire graphics card when it can make do with less? How can I fix this and prevent lag?

The stats of my PC are as follows:
OS: Windows 10
Processor: intel core i7-10750
Memory: 16 GB RAM
Graphics: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650
VRAM: 128 MB

Comment: What is the GPU (integrated or stand alone)?  Is it possible it could be overheating and throttling itself down?

Comment: Could also be that your hardware is failing. Or a bad driver update.

Comment: it may be thermal throttling. Check that your power settings are set to the cooling to active aka "fans first" setting instead of the "downclock first" setting.